# Calling javascript method within a user control .NET 1.1

Tags: javascript, html

I have a user control that has a server side dropdownlist (it needs to be server side).  The user control appears multiple times on a webpage so I need to make the javascript method unique.  I want to validate the ddl selection client side so I don't need a postback.  I found the following example:

---

you need to use this.id

```
function load_v<%= this.ID %>() { alert('anything'); }
```

so that even if you need two or more same controls in the same page they will have different ids. Hope this Helps! cheers :)

---

This works with making the javascript method unique like follows:

```
function DDLSelectionChanged<%=this.ID%>() { code here }
```

But how would I call the method using the onchange event within the asp:dropdownlist tag, e.g.

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="list1".... onchange="JavaScript:DDLSelectionChanged()"...>
```

I tried putting `onchange="JavaScript:DDLSelectionChanged<%=this.ID%>()"` but that doesn't work.

Please remember this is .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this in your server side

DDCONTROL.attributes.add("onchange","javascript:fname(this.id);");

you need to create function named "fname" into javascript with one parameter, that parameter will give you an ID# of particular dropdown control.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, yes I know you can do this.  I don't want the id of the dropdownlist <%=this.id%> gives you the id of the overall control when you place it on a page and it is this id I require.  If I have a javascript method called DDLSelectionChanged within my control, each time I place the control onto the same page duplicate methods of the same name will be created DDLSelectionChanged<%=this.id%> overcomes this by making each version unique by attaching the actual controls name to the method name.